# Is it possible to change the inbuild validator Messages in Django Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

When ever i give wrong format email-id it should throw some other error message rather than
Enter a valid email address

models.py

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    email=models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class PublisherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Publisher
            fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: What do you mean with "miss the email"?

Comment: But yes, it is possible.

Comment: actually when we give a wrong email format it shows
Enter a valid email address 
i want to change it to some other message

Comment: Can you tell what are the ways i can solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`models.EmailField` has `validators.validate_email` as its default validator, and its default error message is `"Enter a valid email address."`.

You can't easily override a field's `default_validators`, so you'd need to use a regular CharField instead, with your own validator.

```
email = models.CharField(
  max_length=254,  # same as EmailField
  blank=True,
  null=True,
  validators=[
    EmailValidator(message="very bad email :("),  # Custom message here.
  ],
)
```